# Ruby on Rails updating list with AJAX breaks order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a list of elements in a certain order. The problem is when I update any element with AJAX this element jumps on the bottom of the list. When I reload page it returns on the right place though. I'd prefer this element to stay in the place when updating.

The list:

```
<div class="shopping-cart">
  <%= render "shopping_cart" %>
</div>
```

_shopping_cart.html.erb:

```
<% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
    <%= render 'carts/cart_row', order_item: order_item %>
<% end %>
```

_cart_row.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity, class: "form-control cart-quantity" %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

update.js.erb:

```
$(".shopping-cart").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'carts/shopping_cart') %>")
```

Any ideas why this happens? Thank you.

UPDATE

The controller code:

```
@order_items = current_order.order_items.order("created_at ASC")
```

And there is no more any AJAX code, all is here, so there is no other sort criteria.

Comment: Need to see the controller code that is actually loading the items. Is there separate code for the AJAX query? If so make sure that query has the same sort criteria.

Comment: Updated initial post

Comment: In that code you're sorting them by "created_at ASC" which means the newest created item will be at the bottom. I'm not sure how you'd get them in any other order unless there is other code somewhere that sorts them into a different order.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of an answer, I'll give you an idea...

--

Firstly, you must remember that with Ajax calls, the issue is *either* going to be an Ajax's appending, or with Rails' data.

I immediately presumed your issue would be that you're just appending your new data to your view. You've done well with the code you have; it is likely an issue with your `@order_items` array.

Here's what I'd do:

```
update.js.erb:
$(".shopping-cart").html("<%=j render 'carts/shopping_cart' %>")

_shopping_cart.html.erb:
<% render 'carts/cart_row', collection: @order_items, as: :order_item %>
```

The controller code:

```
@order_items = current_order.order_items.order :created_at
```

No difference?

Sure.

The way to debug will be like this:

1. Check the `@order_items` object (either with the `network` tab in your browser dev console), or in the Rails logger
2. Check that JS isn't doing anything stupid with the data. If the data is ordered properly, it should append as required.

Comment: Thank you for an answer.
Unfortunately I could not find out what produces this behavior.
As I mentioned when I reload page the element returns on the right place.
So I just used this code to reload specified div right after update:
`$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');`